# Unable to install GithubDesktopSetup.exe

Tags: github-desktop

While I'm trying to install Githubdesktop.exe, I am facing error as "Installation has failed.There was an error while installing the application.Check the setup log for more information".And the error log was as follows:

2017-09-18 07:31:14> Program: Starting Squirrel Updater: --install .

2017-09-18 07:31:15> Program: Starting install, writing to C:\Users\SAMEER\AppData\Local\SquirrelTemp
2017-09-18 07:31:15> Program: About to install to: C:\Users\SAMEER\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop
2017-09-18 07:31:15> CheckForUpdateImpl: Couldn't write out staging user ID, this user probably shouldn't get beta anything: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\SAMEER\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\packages.betaId'.

at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.FileStream..ctor(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter.CreateFile(String path, Boolean append, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.StreamWriter..ctor(String path, Boolean append, Encoding encoding, Int32 bufferSize, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.InternalWriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding, Boolean checkHost)
   at System.IO.File.WriteAllText(String path, String contents, Encoding encoding)
   at Squirrel.UpdateManager.CheckForUpdateImpl.getOrCreateStagedUserId()
2017-09-18 07:31:15> CheckForUpdateImpl: Failed to load local releases, starting from scratch: System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path 'C:\Users\SAMEER\AppData\Local\GitHubDesktop\packages\RELEASES'.
   at System.IO.__Error.WinIOError(Int32 errorCode, String maybeFullPath)
   at System.IO.FileStream.Init(String path, FileMode mode, FileAccess access, Int32 rights, Boolean useRights, FileShare share, Int32 bufferSize, FileOptions options, SECURITY_ATTRIBUTES secAttrs, String msgPath, Boolean bFromProxy, Boolean useLongPath, Boolean checkHost)

Comment: did you run the .exe as an administrator? Also why are you running beta? Get the latest version from here : https://desktop.github.com/ scroll down to Not ready for Desktop Beta?

Comment: @hellyale: the "beta" is what you get when you click on https://desktop.github.com/ - it appears the be the regular release.

Comment: @fearless_fool 10 months ago that was not the case, you could still opt into grabbing the old version when installing.

Comment: @hellyale: I'm sure that's true.  But I'm also getting the same error message today.   My guess is that this problem is common to Electron-based builds since I'm seeing similar comments for Atom.  Would love to find a solution.

Comment: @fearless_fool hmmm System.IO.DirectoryNotFoundException: Could not find a part of the path

Comment: Try manually creating the directory path then reinitiate the install?

Answer (score 0):

The most likely cause of this message is simple: Github Desktop will only run on 64 bit systems.  [There's a long thread in the issues directory](https://github.com/desktop/desktop/issues/1214) that discusses (among other things) why the error message isn't more clear, but the crux is that the message is generated by Squirrel, which the Github Desktop developers don't directly control.

But -- when all is said and done -- the Github Desktop download page could make it a bit more obvious that the app only works under 64 bit systems.  I had to dig to find out that was the case.